# PHP Server displays White page where there is a syntax error

Tags: php, syntax-error

I have PHP 5.5.12 installed on Windows Server 2008 R2.
When I execute a script that has a syntax error "depending on the error" some times I get an error a some times I get a white page! I am not sure what is the issue or how to fix it.

On the top of my script I have the following codes

```
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "C:\phpsites\uat\logs\php-error-logs.log");
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

This should display the error and also log it. but when I get a white page the error is not displayed and it is not logged which is making it hard for me to debug my code.

What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you checked the web server logs?

Comment: changing your settings from within the script is pointless if the code contains a syntax error that causes a fatal parsing error before any of the code actually executes. While developing, you shoul ALWAYS have those settings enabled at the php.ini level, so that they're always on.

Comment: @MarcB you should provide this as an answer ;)

Comment: @MarcB you are right! Thank you. if you provide the answer I will be sure to select it as the correct answer. Thanks a lot